# How to add JS effects on rendering AJAX parts in JSF2?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

In JSF2, I can update part of view by AJAX. I assume part of components tree is just generated/updated on server, rendered to HTML and this HTML is sent to client. Then inserted into DOM where appropriate.

This works, but I wonder if I could add some jQuery (or other JS) effect when I want this new HTML part to appear? What if I want it e.g. to fade in? Can I do this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy if you use Primefaces:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/effects.jsf

Otherwise you could use the `onevent` attribute of the `f:ajax` tag, which accepts a Javascript function name as the value. This function will be called three times during an AJAX request: with `begin`, `complete` and `success` set in the function parameter's status field.

Check page 355 of "Java Server Faces 2.0 - The Complete Reference" for further info.

You can see a working example here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/index.html

**UPDATE:** From the Primefaces users guide:

Effects can also be applied to any JSF component when page is loaded for the first time or after an ajax request is completed. Following example animates messages with pulsate effect after ajax request.

```
<p:messages id="messages"> 
    <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load"> 
        <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" /> 
    </p:effect>
</p:messages> 
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.action}" update="messages"/>
```

Comment: Primefaces is nice, but isn't it applied to component AFTER it is displayed? E.g. by ajax call I render some component, which was hidden before. Isn't it first rendered, and then effect applied?

Comment: No, because the component has an "event" attribute...

An example from the Primefaces users guide:

Effects can also be applied to any JSF component when page is loaded for the first time or after an
ajax request is completed. Following example animates messages with pulsate effect after ajax
request.

`<p:messages id=”messages”>
<p:effect type=”pulsate” event=”load”>
<f:param name=”mode” value=”'show'” />
</p:effect>
</p:messages>
<p:commandButton value=”Save” actionListener=”#{bean.action}”
update=”messages”/>`

(sorry for the formatting, doesn't seem to work in comment fields...)